# How to remove 1 element in a list without Python returning "None"?

Tags: python, list

All the other posts out there currently address the "why" but not the "how".

I have a list created from a dataframe's index called `df.index.to_list()`. Its contents are:

```
['ScreenPorch',
 'BsmtFinSF2',
 'EnclosedPorch',
 'LotArea',
 'MasVnrArea',
 '2ndFlrSF',
 '1stFlrSF',
 'GarageArea',
 'WoodDeckSF',
 'GrLivArea',
 'OpenPorchSF',
 'SalePrice',
 'Id',
 'LotFrontage',
 'YearRemodAdd',
 'BsmtFinSF1',
 'YearBuilt',
 'GarageYrBlt',
 'BsmtUnfSF',
 'TotalBsmtSF']
```

I would like to remove `SalePrice` from this list. However, if I do `print(df.index.to_list().remove('SalePrice'))`, Python returns `None` .

**How** would I return the list without the element `SalePrice`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop` method from `pd.Index`:

```
>>> df.index.drop('SalePrice').to_list()
['ScreenPorch',
 'BsmtFinSF2',
 'EnclosedPorch',
 'LotArea',
 'MasVnrArea',
 '2ndFlrSF',
 '1stFlrSF',
 'GarageArea',
 'WoodDeckSF',
 'GrLivArea',
 'OpenPorchSF',
 'Id',
 'LotFrontage',
 'YearRemodAdd',
 'BsmtFinSF1',
 'YearBuilt',
 'GarageYrBlt',
 'BsmtUnfSF',
 'TotalBsmtSF']
```